# Recommendation for converting from Qt app to Web app

Tags: javascript, html, qt, wt

I currently have a Qt-based GUI application that simply provides a graphical dashboard (guages, graphs, and such) displaying real-time data provided by another application via a TCP connection.  For architectural and security reasons, I have been told that my TCP connection is no longer allowed, and that an HTTPS websocket will be my only conduit.  It was suggested that I convert my app to a webapp using HTML5 and Javascript.  However, I'm not a web programmer, but may consider this an opportunity to learn a new technology.  I want to understand the landscape a little better before making a decision. So, I think my choices are:

1. Convert my app to a web app, giving me all the advantages/disadvantages of web-based apps.  More work for me, as it's a new technology and I already have the Qt/TCP version working fine.  If this is the suggested approach, any suggestions on a development environment/tools would be appreciated.
2. Convert my current Qt app to us a client HTTPS connection rather than a TCP connection. Not sure this is possible. From what I've read, this may not be possible with QtWebKit.  Seems strange?

Maybe there's another choice I'm not considering?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a mixed approach, using WT library. It's c++ (and QT inspired) based.
It has a nice toolkit and supports websockets.

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/examples/

Comment: Wt is based on Boost, not on Qt. Taking into account Wt is in C++, it will allow to re-use non-GUI logic, when porting. But GUI have to be done from the scratch. And it has no LGPL licence.

Answer (score 1):

Porting requires a lot of work. On Qt side there are at least two implementations of WebSockets:

1. [QtWebSocket](https://gitorious.org/qtwebsocket), Qt-based websocket server implementation and alpha-state implementation of websocket client.
2. [WebSocket++](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp), Boost-based  websocket server and client implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through a similar exercise for work recently.  We settled on the Google Web Toolkit (GWT) framework for doing our web apps.  It's completely java-based, meaning you write (almost) everything in Java and the GWT compiler converts it to Javascript for you.  We used the GWT-EventService plugin for pushing data from the server to the clients.

I wish I had know about this WT library before we started though, that looks interesting.

Comment: Porting from Qt to GWT probably isn't any easier than porting from Qt to plain web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [QWebSockets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-index.html), which is a pure Qt implementation of websockets, both for client and server use.

Update: this library is now an integral part of Qt